# How to get Sales Order and Inventory transactions from Quickbooks?

Tags: transactions, quickbooks, inventory

I have implemented quickbooks in my asp.net project I want to get the list of Sales orders and the inventory transactions using quickbooks, I did R&D and did not find any fruitful information. Is it possible to get the lists of sales orders and the inventory transactions list using quickbooks.

Comment: Hey Shahbez - Please add some more details in your question. Also, I would encourage you to please read this link to get good answers on your posts - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Post your code. Also, are you using QuickBooks ONLINE, or QuickBooks FOR WINDOWS?

Comment: I did not write a code yet. I want to know is it possible to get the list of SALES ORDER from quickbooks and Transactions Lists too. I am using Quickbooks rest api in WEB FORMS.